мне нужно после нажатия инлайн кнопки написать ответ в боте, но когда я пишу мне выдает ошибки когда в целом код верный, но он выдает ошибку
def introduction_one(message):
    print('ok')
    markup = markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width = 3)

    Yes = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Да!', callback_data = 'Yes')
    Callmy = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Позвони мне', callback_data = 'Callmy')
    Goodbye = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Немного позже!', callback_data = 'Goodbye')
    markup.add(Yes, Callmy, Goodbye)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'работает', reply_markup = markup)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)

def callback(call):
    if call.message:
        if call.data == 'Yes':
            bot.edit_message_text(chat_id = call.message.chat.id, message_id = call.message.id, text = 'Тогда начнем!')
            bot.register_next_step_handler(call.message, question_one)

def question_one(message):
    question_one_vip = message.text
    print(question_one_vip)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ok')

bot.polling()


добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как задать хороший вопрос

Привет. Какую именно ошибку?

Из-за того, что нет ошибки, точно сказать не могу, но есть предположение, что:

bot.edit_message_text(chat_id = call.message.chat.id, message_id = call.message.id, text = 'Тогда начнем!')

у message нет переменной id, можете попробовать так:
bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.from_user.id, message_id=call.message.message_id, text='Тогда начнем!')

также ошибка может быть в строке:
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)

Возможно, Вам стоит оставить только:
@bot.callback_query_handler(lambda call: True)

Но все же помочь смогу я и другие пользователи только тогда, когда Вы прикрепите полный код и ошибку.
